# Поиск элемента в HTML документе с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html, парсер

Как в PHP можно найти нужный элемент в HTML документе или строке, аля `get_file_content($htmlString);`

Например, есть сайт **site.ru** у него в "голове" есть скрипт `<script src=site.ru></script>`
Нужно проверить, существует ли этот тег  с атрибутом src на сайте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
// Забираете всё что находится по ссылке
$html = file_get_html('http://site.com/');

//Ищите ваш тег, если не найдет вернет null (если я не ошибаюсь)
$el = $html->find('script[src=site.ru]', 0);
```

Больше примеров доступно по ссылке выше.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант, хоть и костыльный, но будет работать из коробки:

```
strripos(file_get_contents('http://site.ru'), '<script src='js/js.js'></script>');
```

Если вернёт integer - значит есть, иначе null